# has_many :through multiple joins table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I'm trying to create a 4 way joins table.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_configurations
  has_many :teams, through: :user_configurations
  has_many :companies, through: :user_configurations

  scope :supervisors, -> { joins(:user_configurations).where(user_configurations: { supervisor: true }) }
  scope :agents, -> { joins(:user_configurations).where(user_configurations: { supervisor: false }) }
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_configurations
  has_many :users, through: :user_configurations
  belongs_to :company_unit
end

class CompanyUnit < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_configurations
  has_many :users, through: :user_configurations
  has_many :teams
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_configurations
  has_many :users, through: :user_configurations
  has_many :company_units
  has_many :teams, through: :company_units
end

class UserConfiguration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
  belongs_to :company, optional: true
  #supervisor:boolean in this table
end
```

When I create I get 2 separate entries into the UserConfiguration Table.

`Company.first.users.create(team_ids: [1])`

`id: 1, user_id: 1, team_id: nil, company_id: 1`

`id: 2, user_id: 1, team_id: 1, company_id: nil`

I don't know if it's good practice to attempt something like this any suggestions will be really helpful thanks. Every search results in trying to do a sql join to query data.

EDIT: Decided not to do this and will try and figure out a different approach.

Comment: What's the Business Model of your example? because your models looks so confusing!

Comment: I added the Company Team relationship. I want to be able to have a User belong to a Team and a Company so that I can delete a Users Team but still have it linked to Company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set it up with indirect relationships instead:

```
class User
  has_many :employments
  has_many :companies, through: :employments
  has_many :positions
  has_many :teams, through: :positions
end

class Company
  has_many :employments
  has_many :users, through: :employments
  has_many :teams, through: :users
end

class Team
  has_many :positions
  has_many :users, through: :positions
  has_many :companies, through: :users
end

# join model between User and Company
class Employment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end

# join model between User and Team
class Position
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

While you could potentially use a single 3 way join model this violates the Single Responsibility Principle and does not map the domain very well.

3 way joins introduce quite a bit of complexity as you cannot simply unlink two records by deleting a row in the join table. And ActiveRecord does not automatically keep track of the foreign key columns.

If you want to add roles to this data model there are a few ways to do it:

### 1 add an [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to the join table:

```
# join model between User and Team
class Position
  enum role: [:grunt, :supervisor]
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

### 2 create a reusable role system.

```
class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

  def has_role?(name, resource = nil)
    roles.exists?(name: name, resource: resource)
  end
end

class Role
  belongs_to :resource, polymorpic: true, optional: true
  has_many :user_roles
end

class UserRole
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

This is a really flexible system lets you attach roles to anything - companies, teams etc. And lets you build systems where the roles can even by defined by end users. Check out the [rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) for a full example.

Comment: I might have made my question a bit to simple. I'm going to update it again. It has 4 joins's and I want to add a supervisor:boolean field to the joins. Going to update the question again

Comment: You should probably just explain what the business model is that you are trying to achieve - not how.

Comment: It might still be better to split it up into separate join tables. What do you think after the update?

Comment: I think I'm going to go and rethink this. The single responsibility rule is being violated. Thanks.

Comment: I added a bit about how to add metadata and roles to this data model.

Comment: Thanks I'll go check it out. The enum is quite interesting. I've never heard of that before.